# Why doesn't a style defined to a class work inside a <div> element?

Tags: html, css

I'm quite new to CSS and HTML and came across a situation where I have a class `example` and a class `credits`. I want some elements inside `example` to have a specific design, but `credits` is general and should apply to the whole document. So I wrote:

```css
.example p {
    text-align: justify;
}
.credits {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
    <h1>Main Title</h1>
    <p class="credits">by Author</p>
  <p class="intro">some info...</p>
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <p>Lots of text...</p>
</div>
```

My problem is: `.credits` style is not applied to `<p class="credits">` element inside the `<div>` and I don't understand why. Can someone explain me the reason?

Comment: It happens because of you have already assigned ```text-align: justify;``` to the ```p``` element which will be taken with priority and hence the same ```p``` element class css selector ```text-align: right;``` is not assigned.. What does your exact requirement?? Do you want to move ```by Author``` to the right??

Comment: @ManirajMurugan thanks for the feedback. I'm still getting used to how cascading works and didn't realize that `.example p` is more specific than `.credits`. I'd like to know how can I get `.credits` rules apply to "by Author" (in this case move "by Author" to the right).

Comment: Have you looked at `!important` ? https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: @JGFMK not yet. Going to take a look at that right now. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I do want to call out that `!important` should be used very sparingly, as @JGFMK's  article says, while it works, it often causes you far more issues down the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into an issue with CSS selector specificity.

While CSS evaluates rules from top to bottom of the stylesheet, it also looks at [selector specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to determine which rule to apply first, second, third, and so forth.

The selector `.example p` has a higher specificity (two selectors) than the selector `.credits` therefor its being applied second and overriding the later selector.

If you update the second selector to have more specificity, (e.g. `.example .credits`) it will give you the output you're looking for.

```css
.example p {
    text-align: justify;
}
.example .credits {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
    <h1>Main Title</h1>
    <p class="credits">by Author</p>
  <p class="intro">some info...</p>
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <p>Lots of text...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm still getting used to how cascading works and didn't realize that `.example p` is more specific than `.credits`. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It can definitely be tricky and selector specificity is one of those weird "gotchas" that end up tripping up a lot of folks. Glad it was helpful!